Is there a non-standard proof (via hyperfinite approximation) that every vector space has a basis?
In chapter 19 of Goldblatt's Lectures on the Hyperreals he discusses Hyperfinite Approximation.

This phenomenon suggests a new methodology for analysing infinite structures by "lifting" a corresponding analysis that is known for finite ones.

In section 19.8 he discusses Hyperfinite Dimensional Vector Spaces and derives a theorem of approximation:

Theorem 19.8.2 If $V$ is a real vector space, then in any enlargement of a universe over $V$ there is a hyperreal space $V^+$ of hyperfinite dimension with:
$$V\subset V^+ \subset {}^*V$$

I feel there should be a way to "push down" the basis of $V^+$ to a basis for $V$.
I have tried several approaches but the consistent problem is that hyperfinite sums that land in $V$ don't neatly transfer to finite sums, because $V$ isn't an internal entity in the enlargement.
Does anyone know a proof via hyperfinite approximation that vector spaces over any field have bases?

You may want to add something in the title to specify that this question deals with hyperfinite sets/nonstandard analysis to attract the correct audience.

It's nigh-impossible to argue that compelling¹ proofs of a certain form cannot exist, and in my experience as a proof theorist, such claims, even when made by seasoned mathematicians, tend to be wrong more often than not. This time, sadly, it's my turn to claim that you won't find a compelling proof of your desired form.
I base this claim on two points. First, my PhD involved examining the limitations of hyperfinite approximation methods (and their far-fetched extensions) in algebra, so while I don't consider myself a seasoned mathematician by any means, I can claim at least some relevant domain expertise. Second, while I would actually be thrilled if someone proved me wrong and wrote down a solid proof based on hyperfinite approximation, I think I can explain why such proofs are unlikely below the line.

Nelson's Internal Set Theory (IST) is an extension of usual Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF) with primitives for doing nonstandard analysis. I will not cover IST in any depth here: plenty of good resources explain how it works elsewhere.
Now, IST contains the Axiom of Choice as one of its axioms, but we can simply drop it, and end up with the theory IST-C, Internal Set Theory with the Axiom of Choice removed. It's not hard to check that IST-C establishes the (IST analogue) of Goldblatt's Theorem 19.8.2. (IST-C proves that there is a hyperfinite set that contains all the standard elements of $V$ and since every finitely generated vector space has a basis, this follows).
As Karel Hrbacek diligently proved in his article Axiom of Choice in nonstandard set theory, the theory IST-C constitutes a conservative extension of ZF + the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem.
In the 1980s, Andreas Blass showed that existence of bases implies the Axiom of Choice over ZF. But a well-known result of Halpern and Levy states that ZF + the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem does not suffice to prove the Axiom of Choice (a simple model construction is given here). It follows that ZF + the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem does not prove that every vector space has a basis either!
In turn, this means that IST-C cannot prove that every vector space has a basis! But IST-C proves Theorem 19.8.2, and unless you invoked the Axiom of Choice somewhere, it can also formalize your attempts to push down a basis of $V^+$ to $V$ (which therefore won't work).
Any argument that goes from the conclusion of Theorem 19.8.2 to "$V$ has a basis" will have to invoke the Axiom of Choice in some explicit or implicit form. But then one might as well use it as part of a straightforward transfinite induction to conclude that $V$ has a basis. This is already a very simple argument, making it very unlikely that having a hyperfinite approximation around could simplify it even further, or add anything meaningful. But even if we were happy with a more complicated proof, there is a general "missing ingredient" issue that prevents us from progressing further. Inclusion chains $V \subseteq W$ won't normally help one "push down" bases for $W$ onto bases for $V$, since the existence of two vector spaces $V \subseteq W$ such that $W$ has a basis but $V$ has no basis, is consistent with ZF (and even the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem). So to make a strategy like this work, one will need additional results which attest to this particular $W$ (i.e. $V^+$) being special in some way that makes pushing down bases plausible (by invoking AC somewhere, but without just invoking AC to construct a basis of $V$ directly). I doubt that hyperfinite approximations are special in any relevant way, and it' s not clear to me whether any vector space is.
In summary: the theory IST-C can construct hyperfinite approximations and should be able to formalize arguments of this sort, but definitely lacks the power to prove every vector space has a basis. Since invoking the Axiom of Choice will be required and the ideas behind the known AC proofs are dead simple, proofs that involve hyperfinite approximation are unlikely to offer anything beyond the standard argument.

¹ There are, of course, proofs that use hyperfinite approximation in some trivial, superficial or eliminable way; e.g. take a hyperfinite approximation of $V$, then run one of the usual standard proofs that $V$ has a basis. You can dress this up, but the proofs you get won't be compelling: there will be no new ideas in them, just the ideas behind the well-known standard proofs (unlike e.g. the nonstandard proof of IVT, which genuinely contains novel insights).

Thank you, this is an incredibly comprehensive answer.

Thanks for the bounty award Noah Schweber, glad you liked the answer.
